# How do i find if element is not in a ruby array?

Tags: ruby

Ok so i have this array

```
 array
 => [1620, 3093]
```

and I have a integer

```
 num
 => 1620
```

is there an easy way to see if there is another number in the array that is not `num`

so for example

is there another number in the array that doesnt match `num`. So for the above example i would return true but if array was `[1620, 1620]` then i would return false

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
arr.any?{|x| x != num }
```

The above should work fine, is readable and efficient too!

Comment: Nice trick! My instinct was also to reach for a #reject #size combo like @Deefour's solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
array.select{|array_num| array_num != num}.length > 0
```

EDIT: or even cleaner:

```
(array - [num]).empty?
```

Answer (score 2):

```
array.reject{ |a| a == num }.size > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Join the sorted array with a separator and find if there is a match with 2 adjacent numbers.

array.sort.join(",").include?("#{num},#{num}")